# How to call a javascript function in runtime in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a click event which works fine in all other browsers except `IE8`

I tried

```
document.getElementById('xxx').click  -- returns function called
document.getElementById('xxx').click() -- object not supported 
document.querySelectorAll('xxx').click  -- not supported
$("#xx").trigger("click")  -- not supported
$(".xx").trigger("click") --not supported
```

In html i have `<div id="xxx" click="functionname('param1','param2')"></div>`

Now the `document.getElementById('xxx').click` returns the function returned

ie `functionname(param1,param2)`

How can call this function at this time? like i want to execute this function

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309653/ie8-onclick-handler-event

Answer (score 0):

Add function bracket. Otherwise you will get function definition

```
document.getElementById('xxx').click()
```

or

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false, 0, null);

var cb = document.getElementById(id);
cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: use dispatchEvent function