# Jquery .click() called three times

Tags: javascript, jquery

## What I've tried:

I'm almost expecting this to be flagged as a duplicate, but the first ten possible duplicate solutions did not work for me. I've tried `unbind()`, `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` (however, my understanding of the function isn't the best), but my `.click()` function fires three times in the `overlayClicked()` function.

## What I have:

I have three `<div>`s that make up the body so far: the navigation drawer, the menu handle, and the overlay.

The handle is place relatively to the the drawer so that when the drawer opens and closes, it moves with it. Only when the handle is clicked, using a `<label>` with a hidden `<input type="checkbox">`. When the handle is clicked, (and this part works fine) it calls `handleClicked(cb)` which then either opens or closes the drawer, and sets the third `<div>`, the overlay, from `display: none` to `display: block` and fades it in.

The part that doesn't work is I also have another function, `overlayClicked()`, that obviously, when the overlay is clicked, I want it to click the checkbox from above, close the drawer, and again hide the overlay. (Hopefully this all makes sense so far).

```js
function handleClicked(cb){
    if (cb.checked){
        $(".navbar").css("left", "0px");
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(500);
    }else{
        $(".navbar").css("left", "-202.77px");
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(500);
    }
    console.log("handle");
}

function overlayClicked(){
    $("#handle").click();
}
```

```css
:root {
   --light-green-rgb: 142, 167, 128;
   --light-green-hex: #8EA780;
   --green-rgb: 91, 110, 82;
   --green-hex: #5B6E52;
   --dark-green-rgb: 37, 52, 29;
   --dark-green-hex: #25341D;
}

.overlay {
   position   : fixed;
   top        : 0;
   left       : 0;
   width      : 100%;
   height     : 100%;
   background : #000;
   opacity    : 0.6;
   filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
   z-index    : 998;
   display    : none;
   }

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    left: -202.77px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(91, 110, 82, 0.9);
    border-right: 2.77px solid var(--dark-green-hex);
    transition: left .5s;
}

label.navbar-handle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

.navbar-handle-div {
    position: relative;
    right: -209.77px;
    top: 7px;
    border: 3px double var(--dark-green-hex);
    background-color: var(--green-hex);
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}

.navbar-handle-line {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 6.28%;
    border: 2px solid var(--dark-green-hex);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-handle-space {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 14.28%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay" onclick="overlayClicked()"></div>
        
        <div class="navbar">
            
            <div class="navbar-handle-div">
                <label for="handle" class="navbar-handle">
                    <div class="navbar-handle-space"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-handle-line"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-handle-space"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-handle-line"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-handle-space"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-handle-line"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-handle-space"></div>
                </label>
                <input style="display: none;" id="handle" type="checkbox" onclick="handleClicked(this)"/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

## Expected behavior:

Obviously, I want to click the overlay, and have it call `overlayClicked()`, with it simply unchecking the checkbox, closing the drawer, and fading the overlay out.

## Actual behavior:

As you can see, when `handleClicked()` is called, I log "handle" to the console, and when I click on the overlay, it logs "handle" three times, closes the drawer, fades the overlay out, and then it flashes the overlay, fading it in, and then fading it out, *without opening the drawer again*. I'd imagine that's simply because I'm setting the `left` to 0, and then setting it to hidden again, so that's not really my concern.

Comment: @CalebTaylor Capturing should rarely (if ever) be used. A better solution is to just call `stopPropagation()` in the lowest handler to prevent further bubbling.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Good point, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @ScottMarcus Where would I add the `stopPropagation()` call, then? I tried it at the top and bottom of both functions.

Comment: I haven't really looked over your code, but you could try adding the event argument to `overlayClicked` and add the call there: `function overlayClicked(event){ event.stopPropagation();
    $("#handle").click();
}`

Comment: I feel kinda dumb not realizing I had to define the event, but that gave me an error: `Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined`

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I hadn't looked over your code that much and that function isn't directly being called from an event, so you get that error. But, I just tried your code as is and it seems to work just fine. When I click the overlay, I get one message in the console, not 3 and then the overlay fades out.

Comment: We don't debug live sites, but please add the relevant CSS to your question because the size and position of the overlay is probably what's making it work here and not in your actual code.

Comment: added css to my question

Comment: Hmm. Well, as you can see right here in your question, it seems to work as it should.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that... That's pretty frustrating. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the best thing to fire the event in code like this :

```
$("#handle").click();
```

instead try to call the handler and stop event propagation after that:

```
<div class="overlay" onclick="overlayClicked(event)"></div>
```

- 

```
function handleClicked(cb){
    if (cb.checked){
        $(".navbar").css("left", "0px");
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(500);
    }else{
        $(".navbar").css("left", "-202.77px");
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(500);
    }
    console.log("handle");
}

function overlayClicked(event){
    handleClicked($("#handle"))
    if (event.stopPropagation){
       event.stopPropagation();
   }
   else if(window.event){
      window.event.cancelBubble=true;
   }
}
```

See also this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108218/2109287

And this on events bubbling:
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

EDIT:

I had to add a `.prop` call to make sure the checkbox is unchecked so that it doesn't reverse expected behavior.

```
function overlayClicked(event){
    handleClicked($("#handle"))
    $("#handle").prop("checked", false);
    if (event.stopPropagation){
       event.stopPropagation();
   }
   else if(window.event){
      window.event.cancelBubble=true;
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked! I figured it was bad practice to just call a `.click` and I know know why. Thanks

Comment: Just shout out to my edit: I had to add the `.prop` call to make sure the checkbox gets unchecked when clicking the overlay or else it was flipping the fade/drawer behavior.

Comment: No need to check for `window.event` if you use the event object argument

Comment: @charlietfl I believe this is only needed for IE < 9 , see this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309741/2109287)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass a handler method into your `click` event registration. Here:

```
function overlayClicked(){
    $("#handle").click( event => event.stopPropagation() );
}
```